# Cython, Complex values, and BM3D algorithm

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, cython, 3d-reconstruction

I am working on a image reconstruction algorithm and I found [this repo](https://github.com/ericmjonas/pybm3d) online that would work great with my code, but unfortunately it doesnt seem to support complex valued calculations. I've read up on cython the past couple of days, but I'm pressed for time and I wanted to ask for advice before bull-dozering all over the code.

To be more exact, this is the Cython file:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp cimport bool
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "../bm3d_src/mt19937ar.h":
double mt_genrand_res53()

cdef extern from "../bm3d_src/bm3d.h":
int run_bm3d( const float sigma, vector[float] &img_noisy, 
              vector[float] &img_basic,
              vector[float] &img_denoised, 
              const unsigned width, 
              const unsigned height, 
              const unsigned chnls, 
              const bool useSD_h, 
              const bool useSD_w, 
              const unsigned tau_2D_hard, 
              const unsigned tau_2D_wien, 
              const unsigned color_space)

cdef extern from "../bm3d_src/utilities.h":
int save_image(char * name, vector[float] & img, 
               const unsigned width, 
               const unsigned height, 
               const unsigned chnls)


def hello():
return "Hello World"

def random():
return mt_genrand_res53()

cpdef float[:, :, :] bm3d(float[:, :, :] input_array, 
                      float sigma, 
                      bool useSD_h = True, 
                      bool useSD_w = True, 
                      str tau_2D_hard = "DCT", 
                      str tau_2D_wien = "DCT"
                      ):
"""
sigma: value of assumed noise of the noisy image;
input_array : input image, H x W x channum
useSD_h (resp. useSD_w): if true, use weight based
on the standard variation of the 3D group for the
first (resp. second) step, otherwise use the number
of non-zero coefficients after Hard Thresholding
(resp. the norm of Wiener coefficients);

tau_2D_hard (resp. tau_2D_wien): 2D transform to apply
on every 3D group for the first (resp. second) part.
Allowed values are 'DCT' and 'BIOR';
# FIXME : add color space support; right now just RGB
"""

cdef vector[float] input_image
cdef vector[float] basic_image
cdef vector[float] output_image
cdef vector[float] denoised_image

height = input_array.shape[0]
width = input_array.shape[1]
chnls = input_array.shape[2]


# convert the input image
input_image.resize(input_array.size)
pos = 0
for i in range(input_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(input_array.shape[1]):
        for k in range(input_array.shape[2]):
            input_image[pos] = input_array[i, j, k]
            pos +=1 


if tau_2D_hard == "DCT":
    tau_2D_hard_i = 4
elif tau_2D_hard == "BIOR" :
    tau_2D_hard_i = 5
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown tau_2d_hard, must be DCT or BIOR")

if tau_2D_wien == "DCT":
    tau_2D_wien_i = 4
elif tau_2D_wien == "BIOR" :
    tau_2D_wien_i = 5
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown tau_2d_wien, must be DCT or BIOR")

# FIXME someday we'll have color support
color_space = 0

ret = run_bm3d(sigma, input_image, basic_image, output_image, 
               width, height, chnls, 
               useSD_h, useSD_w, 
               tau_2D_hard_i, tau_2D_wien_i, 
               color_space)
if ret != 0:
    raise Exception("run_bmd3d returned an error, retval=%d" % ret)

cdef np.ndarray output_array = np.zeros([height, width, chnls], 
                                        dtype = np.float32)


pos = 0
for i in range(input_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(input_array.shape[1]):
        for k in range(input_array.shape[2]):
            output_array[i, j, k] = output_image[pos]
            pos +=1 

return output_array
```

How would I go about making the most minimal changes such that it'll work with numpy array with dtype='complex'?

Cheers!

Comment: Given that the c++ code doesn't support complex values, how do you imagine the algorithm should be applied to complex numbers. You could just call abs on the input array? Or work with the real and imaginary parts separately?

Comment: I'm currently testing several different ways of approach, like you suggested abs() and imaginary and real separate, as well as separating to phase and magnitude. I wasn't actually aware that there is no support of complex values in c++, so I guess this answers my question. Thank you David.

Comment: No, there is support for complex values in c++, but the library you want to use doesn't look to accept them, so you'd have to modify that too. It isn't clear from your question exactly what bits of code you're wanting to change (the Cython, the C++, both?) and what mathematical outcome you're expecting.

Comment: I am working with images in the Fourier Domain (MRI). [BM3D](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/GCF-BM3D/) is a state of the art denoiser which I'm trying to experiment with, but as you might tell, I haven't worked much with Cython before this week. My questions boils down to what'll be the simplest work around to give a natural solution to working with complex values within BM3D. I tried separating the signal to Phase and Magnitude, as well as Imaginary and Real, which have given me somewhat decent results, but it also requires manipulation of values of noise given within my algorithms.